# Hibernate Save() option not returning any object

Tags: java, hibernate

I am new to Hibernate,I am using save() inorder to store the object in database

```
import java.io.*;//Bean Class
public class Employee implements Serializable
{
String name;
int age,id;

public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() 
{
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) 
{
    this.name = name;
}
public int getAge() 
{
    return age;
}
public void setAge(int age) 
{
    this.age = age;
}
}

public class Testclass1 //This is the Test Class
{   
    public static void main(String args[])
        {
        Employee eobj=new Employee();
        eobj.setName("Rajesh");
        eobj.setAge(23);        
        Configuration con=new Configuration();
        con.configure("Configuration1.xml");
        SessionFactory sf=con.buildSessionFactory();
        Session s=sf.openSession();
        Transaction t=s.beginTransaction();
        Object objectE=s.save(eobj);
        Employee Eobject=(Employee)objectE;
        System.out.println("Eage="+Eobject.getAge()+"EName="+Eobject.getName());
        t.commit();
        s.close();
        sf.close();
        }
}
```

I am trying to get that saved object and use that saved object to display the Id and Name.

But i am getting ClassCastException

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to com.online.javascript.Employee
    at com.online.javascript.Testclass1.main
```

Comment: save method returns assigned identifier, that's why objectE is not your persisted object, but your object's persistence id. 

`Employee Eobject=(Employee)objectE; - you need to remove this line.`

Comment: @fg78nc can you explain what is assigned identifier,I needed the return object and check whether the Object has inserted the correct value or not

Comment: Every persisted entity must have persistence identifier, which corresponds to key in database. 
In you case, when you are saving employee, you need to assign (can be auto-generated) id of the employee. When employee entity will be saved to underlying database, that id will be saved in database as employee's primary key, so you can retrieve it from db later. Also you need to annotate your class `@Entity` and your id with `@Id` and `@GeneratedValue`.

Comment: Please specify the primary key in your pojo class. Also state it with auto increment property. You can get the id by following this.

Answer (score 0):

Exception is very clear.That is, "The session.save(eobj) returns the id of the object.Cant cast it to Employee"
You can get the object by

```
emp =  (Employee ) session.get(Employee .class, id); // id = s.save(eemp)
```

Comment: why id is returned,i wanted to return the Object.What should i do inorder to get the object

Comment: i have worked in some other Programs, where i will get the return object by default.So is there anyother way i can achieve the solution

Comment: That's how Hibernate API is written. Have you used JPA EntityManager API, it would return persisted object itself, not the id.
`em.persist(obj);`